# FHIR Medication Administration - Current Dose

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

I need a way of saying where we are currently within a dose of medication.

Like 5 execution out of 7

or Dose Administration number 5

Does anyone know how to express this in the event objects or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [MedicationAdministration](https://simplifier.net/core-base-resources/MedicationAdministration/) resource? It has a 'note' field where you could put this in, and also a text field for the dosage.

Comment: I think the text field is for a hand written dosage instruction, from what I see here: http://hl7.org/fhir/medicationadministration.html  but the note might work.

Answer (score -1):

I put in a change ticket for this functionality within FHIR, but for now I am saving it in Medical Administration Event History:

But I have to extend action to have quantity.

http://hl7.org/fhir/medicationadministration.html

```
"medicationAdministration":{
        "eventHistory":[{
            "action":{
                "coding": [{
                    "system": "http://www.kindred.com/proTouch",
                    "code": "lastDelivery",
                    "display": "Last Delivery"
                }],
                "dateTime":"2016-09-22 13:06:20"
            }
        },{
            "action":{
                "coding": [{
                    "system": "http://www.kindred.com/proTouch",
                    "code": "dosesAdministered",
                    "display": "Doses Administered"
                }]
                "quantity":2
            }
        }]
    }
```